# Erlang Shell Tunnel

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Is it possible to create a shell tunnel, connect to it from outside, and send commands to it?

I want to manage nodes and send arbitrary commands from outside of Erlang without creating an API.

```
erlshell = Erlshell(host="localhost")
res = erlshell.exec("""
  A = 2,
  B = 5,
  A + B
")
print(res)
```

I found this project (http://erlport.org/) but it hasn't had activity in 6 years.

Comment: You could run an Erlang ssh daemon: https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssh/using_ssh.html#running-an-erlang-ssh-daemon

Comment: Why not keeping your Erlang shell *active* inside a terminal multiplexer such as tmux, and then you can always attach/connect to the shell anytime to issue any command? This way the normal way of *connecting* to it is through the normal way like ssh.